# Shortcut to shutdown menu

Tags: 17.10

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Give keyboard focus to the top bar but arrow buttons navigate worked only in Actions tab. Focus can be switch between all items using tab or arrow <kbd>↤</kbd> and <kbd>↦</kbd> but arrow buttons <kbd>↥</kbd> and <kbd>↧</kbd> and button <kbd>Enter</kbd> do not worked.

Missing full navigation in top bar like Unity <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To switch between Activities (I guess that's what you mean by "Actions"?), you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>. There you can navigate using both <kbd>↤</kbd>/<kbd>↦</kbd> and <kbd>↥</kbd>/<kbd>↧</kbd> keys to navigate through Activities. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to focus on selected Activity.

Comment: Activities all ok. But mssing keyboard navigation in to the system menu (shutdown menu, system settings, etc) like Unity  Alt+F10

Comment: @AndrisPetrams Then there's still Super+m to open Notifications menu and then ↤/↦ to navigate through top bar menus.

Comment: Yes navigate ↤/↦ worked (only show top bar items content) but ↥/↧/Enter do not worked

Comment: Top-bar items full keyborad navigation working after Super+M and move cursor above top-bar item content using mouse. But without mouse focus can not get on item contents.